# How to recover ubuntu back to normal after interrupting the update?

Tags: boot, updates, 15.10

Today morning Ubuntu prompt me to update my ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10, I started the upgrade process, but the process hangs with the message (something like) halt because of too many errors, I had to force stop the process and Restart the computer, now since than it has been stuck in the loading ubuntu screen (gnome screen) with the error in the background

> Failed to start monitor and control system power state.
>   See `systemctl powerd.service` for details.

and a never ending wait

> A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit (hours)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to get a console some way, and type `dpkg --configure -a` as root.
This command will configure already installed packages.
After it is finished try to boot back to the system and upgrade it the way you like.

In the worst case one can do it by using a livecd and chrooting to the original system.

Answer (score 0):

You can get into a root console by booting into recovery mode. On the Grub screen, select Advanced Options for Ubuntu, then select the entry marked "recovery mode". A lot of text will scroll as Ubuntu loads, then you'll get recovery options. Select the bottom option for a root prompt, and then enter "mount -o rw,remount /" to get read/write access. Now you can run "dpkg --configure -a" as previously answered by mestia.